# Image goes beyond column width in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4, responsive

I’m using Bootstrap grid incorrectly and I’m can’t for the life of me work it out!
I designed [this page](https://8000-fuchsia-tern-gng96jz6.ws-eu07.gitpod.io/about.html) so that it would split the image alongside the copy. I thought a simple split col-6 row in “Over 40 years Media Experience” would do it but it looks like the image is over 50%.

I want the image to go the width of the column. I’ve tried img-fluid and img-responsive but nothing is working as well as the HUGE (and inelegant!) workaround (written in the following two containers.

If anyone could take a look and see if I’ve missed anything crashingly obvious. I’d be forever grateful.

````
                <div class="container container-head">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">

                            <h2>Over 40 years’ <span class="spotlight">media experience</span></h2>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6-md media">
                            <div class="fsm-about-pic image-fluid">
                            <img src="images/about-joncorrinenew640.jpg" 
                                    alt="Jon and Corinne from Full Story Media">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="col-6-md media-body">
                                    <p><i class="far fa-circle"></i> Full Story Media is led by us: <a href="#jon">Jon Card</a> 
                                        and <a href="#corinne">Corinne Card</a>. <!-- this could be a subtitle now with bit below as a testimonial like the client quotes -->
                                    </p>
                                    <p><i class="far fa-circle"></i> With over 40 years’ media experience between
                                        us, we have written for every national newspaper in the UK, plus many other titles
                                        worldwide.</p>
                                    <p><i class="far fa-circle"></i> We are entrepreneurial, media savvy and believe
                                        in the power of storytelling.</p>
                                    <p><i class="far fa-circle"></i> We ensure our clients get the best advice. In fact, we
                                        insist on it. </p>
                                    <p><i class="far fa-circle"></i> We are also completely transparent about our
                                        methods and tend to give away all of our knowledge.</p>
                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            
            </section> ```
````

Comment: Add this Class on img `img-fluid`

Comment: Ah thanks I added that class but it's still staying the same size -looks particularly bad on mobile - is it because the text box can flex?

Comment: The correct class is `col-md-6` which will give 6 units to column above medium devices. If this doesnot solve what you want to achieve, can you please elaboarte a bit more your issue ?

Comment: That fixed it thanks! A silly slip. Thanks for your help.